# Show hidden element

Tags: javascript, html

I have `div` and hidden `span` on it. I want to show it by button clicking. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>register page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="register-form">           
        <label>Username<span id="register-username-label" class="label label-important" style="visibility: hidden;">Username can't be empty</span></label>
        <input id="register-username-input" type="text" placeholder="Type username..."/>
        <button id="register-submit" onclick="show_element('register-username-label')" class="btn">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my js file:

```
function show_element (id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

When i button clicked span does not show. Why? It shows very fast and than hidden again.

Chrome developer tools console doesn't show errors too.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the Console in inspect element show? Is there an error? Is the js function in the header? If it not, then is the js file included? Is the function available before being called from html? Are you passing the correct id to the function?

Comment: Your code is working in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/cK6Nb/ - can you show us where the JS is in your HTML file?

Comment: make sure you are sending the correct id to show_element function

Comment: Your inline style should be closed with a semi colon `;` - `visibility: hidden;` Just Sayin'..

Comment: unopened tag found in your markup. `<label>` was not opened. is it a typo?

Comment: Does your button do a postback? -> "It shows very fast and than hidden again."

Comment: @Wezly it doesn't have to be. Semicolons within te `style` tag are more separators than anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `return false` to your button onClick() event.
Like this:

```
<button id="register-submit" onclick="show_element('register-username-label'); return false;" class="btn">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your function before your first call to the function is being made. Normally it can be achieved by putting the function code inside a script tag nested inside the `head` of your HTML.

Like this:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function show_element (id) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but this code works:

```
    <html>

    <head>

    <script>
    function show_element (id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <span id="register-username-label" class="label label-important" style="visibility: hidden">Username can't be empty</span>
      <button id="register-submit" onclick="show_element('register-username-label')" class="btn">Register</button>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**EDIT**

I just read your edit. Btw i think your absolute path may causes problem.

Try this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>register page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/test.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="register-form">           
            <label>Username<span id="register-username-label" class="label label-important" style="visibility: hidden;">Username can't be empty</span></label>
            <input id="register-username-input" type="text" placeholder="Type username..."/>
            <button id="register-submit" onclick="show_element('register-username-label')" class="btn">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: More of a comment than an answer, wouldn't you have said?

Comment: Maybe because i just changed some part of his code. I removed </label> end tag because it was an XML mistake. Btw i add html tags just to let him try that code... and just see how it works...